# Get the jsonb entity field

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

In short, I have Hibernate, Spring, PostgreSQL and entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
@DynamicUpdate
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer number;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Information information;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Social social;
}
```

Queries of this kind work fine:

```
Account findByNumber(Integer number);
```

I need to make a request of this kind:

```
@Query(value = "select social from accounts where number = :number", nativeQuery = true)
Social findSocialByNumber(@Param("number") int number);
```

When executing the query written above, I get an error:
`No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111`

Social class:

```
public class Social {
    private Friends friends;
    private Mail mail;

    public Friends getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(Friends friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    public Mail getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(Mail mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
}
```

I tried a bunch of annotations in different quantities and combinations, but I couldn't get the Social object. How can I get a Social object by querying the database?

Comment: Try to use indexed parameters instead of named parameters. I mean, change `:number` for `?1` in your SQL query.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error is the same: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Comment: Is Social class an entity class (`@Entity`) ?